# Sending a C++ image to python server

Tags: python, c++, opencv, boost

All welcome. I'm trying to do something like video stream client-server applications.

There is a client in C++, there is a server in Python. I need send a C ++ image to the python server.

I tried, but did not achieve anything.

C++ Code:

// main

```
int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    DataManager* m = new DataManager(io_service);
    DesktopReader* r = new DesktopReader(GetDesktopWindow());

    m->ConnectToSocket("127.0.0.1", 9191);

    Mat s;

    while (1) {

        r->GetDesktopMat(s);


        int imgSize = s.total() * s.elemSize();
        uchar *iptr = s.data;

        cout << imgSize << endl;

        m->SendData(s.data, imgSize);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

// Data manager:

```
void DataManager::SendData(uchar* data, int size) {

    boost::system::error_code error;

    socket.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(data, size), error);

}
```

// DesktopReader:

```
void DesktopReader::GetDesktopMat(Mat &src)
{
    HDC hwindowDC, hwindowCompatibleDC;

    int height, width, srcheight, srcwidth;
    HBITMAP hbwindow;
    BITMAPINFOHEADER  bi;

    hwindowDC = GetDC(hwnd);
    hwindowCompatibleDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hwindowDC);
    SetStretchBltMode(hwindowCompatibleDC, COLORONCOLOR);

    RECT windowsize;    // get the height and width of the screen
    GetClientRect(hwnd, &windowsize);

    srcheight = windowsize.bottom;
    srcwidth = windowsize.right;
    height = windowsize.bottom / 1;
    width = windowsize.right / 1;

    src.create(height, width, CV_8UC4);

    hbwindow = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hwindowDC, width, height);
    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
    bi.biWidth = width;
    bi.biHeight = -height; 
    bi.biPlanes = 1;
    bi.biBitCount = 32;
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;

    SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow);
    StretchBlt(hwindowCompatibleDC, 0, 0, width, height, hwindowDC, 0, 0, srcwidth, srcheight, SRCCOPY); 
    GetDIBits(hwindowCompatibleDC, hbwindow, 0, height, src.data, (BITMAPINFO *)&bi, DIB_RGB_COLORS); 
    DeleteObject(hbwindow);
    DeleteDC(hwindowCompatibleDC);
    ReleaseDC(hwnd, hwindowDC);
}
```

Python:

```
while True:
    try:
        data = client.recv(8294400) # 8294400 - image size. From: int imgSize = s.total() * s.elemSize();
        if data:
            img = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(data, np.uint8), 1)
            print(img) # There i got None
        else:
            raise print('Client disconnected')
    except:
        client.close()
        return False
```

What is wrong in the code?
How can I get a C ++ image in python?

Comment: You're most likely using TCP/IP, which is a streaming protocol – when you `client.recv(8294400)`, you will receive the data that is available *right now*, but at most 8294400 octets. There are plenty of introductions to TCP programming online and in books.

Comment: There is also not a hint of error handling on the C++ side.